# Message box for null fields

Tags: vba, error-handling, null, messagebox

I am trying to create a database for part locations. Three of the fields (JobNumber, PartNumber and Location) are required fields and I have an If statement written to check for Nulls and error handling to give a message box. After the message box is closed, it will let me return to the form but it will not allow me to edit the field again AND it still adds the incomplete data to the table. Any advice?

```
Private Sub cmdAddNew_Click()

If IsNull(Me.JobNumber) Then
GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err

    ElseIf IsNull(Me.PartNumber) Then
    GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err
    
        ElseIf IsNull(Me.Location) Then
        GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err
End If
On Error GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err

   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
   If (MacroError <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
        End If

cmdAddNew_Click_Exit:


Exit Sub

cmdAddNew_Click_Err:
MsgBox "Job Number, Part Number and Location are required."


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Cancel = True in your second if statement should fix this.

```
Private Sub cmdAddNew_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.JobNumber) Then
        GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err

    ElseIf IsNull(Me.PartNumber) Then
        GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err
    
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.Location) Then
        GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err
    End If
On Error GoTo cmdAddNew_Click_Err

   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
   If (MacroError <> 0) Then
       Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
        Cancel = True
   End If

cmdAddNew_Click_Exit:


Exit Sub

cmdAddNew_Click_Err:
MsgBox "Job Number, Part Number and Location are required."


End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could define functions to check for a null value and return a boolean result:

```
Function isvalid(Field as string) As Boolean
    If IsNull(field)
        isvalid = False
    Else
        isvalid = True
    End If
End Function

Sub Check_valid()

    Call isvalid(field 1)
    Call isvalid(f2)
    Call isvalid(f3)

    If isvalid(field 1) = false Or isvalid(f2) = false Or isvalid(f3) = false Then
        msgbox "Job Number, Part Number and Location are required."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I edited my code a little bit more and added the "Cancel" statement. However, when I go back to edit the field boxes again and one of the required values is missing, it does not check for null values again before adding the data to the table.